# Can't install POS.net to Windows 10

Tags: printing, opos, pos-for-.net, pos.net

I need to install SDK for Epson Printer, but it needs to install Microsoft POS.net

but when i try install MS POS.net it is not complete.

at step " register wmi provider " and it is rolling back action

attached screen shot

[image]

Event Log:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        MsiInstaller
Date:          5/9/2020 2:39:48 AM
Event ID:      11708
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          OSN\ikrami
Computer:      OSN
Description:
Product: Microsoft POS for .NET 1.14.1 -- Installation failed.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="MsiInstaller" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">11708</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-05-09T00:39:48.925461900Z" />
    <EventRecordID>343357</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>OSN</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-2760364576-2455459765-4038222974-1001" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Product: Microsoft POS for .NET 1.14.1 -- Installation failed.</Data>
    <Data>(NULL)</Data>
    <Data>(NULL)</Data>
    <Data>(NULL)</Data>
    <Data>(NULL)</Data>
    <Data>(NULL)</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Binary>7B39333532413734312D373634382D343644412D383036462D3434454436343839304241347D</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Are you running as a non-administrative user, or are there policies or other settings that prevent you from installing or configuring such features?

Comment: running as administrator, also i changed the comparability to be for previous windows version and still not install

Comment: Please check if it is recorded in the event log. Or check the contents including the pages before and after this article. [WMI Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-troubleshooting) If the survey doesn't progress, ask a question in the Microsoft forum or send a Windows 10 feedback.

Comment: it is recorded in Event Log, Installation Failed:

  <Data>Product: Microsoft POS for .NET 1.14.1 -- Installation failed.</Data> 
  <Data>(NULL)</Data> 
  <Data>(NULL)</Data> 
  <Data>(NULL)</Data> 
  <Data>(NULL)</Data> 
  <Data>(NULL)</Data> 
  <Data />

Comment: The comment format and layout are poor, so please add it to the question article. If you don't see the details, it's a good idea to ask questions and give feedback to the forums as in the last comment.

Comment: I added event log details to question

Comment: These articles seem relevant. Please investigate based on these. [Event ID: 11708 Source: MsiInstaller](http://www.eventid.net/display-eventid-11708-source-MsiInstaller-eventno-1686-phase-1.htm), [Windows Installerが失敗する場合の対処](https://messiah-annex.hatenablog.jp/entry/2006/02/15/181306), [Event ID - 11708 Source MsiInstaller](http://kb.eventtracker.com/evtpass/evtpages/EventId_11708_MsiInstaller_46225.asp), [Event log message indicates that the Windows Installer ...](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/help/974524/event-log-message-indicates-that-the-windows-installer-reconfigured-al)